# Start Application on Start up

Tags: fedora, rhel

I am currently using RHEL 7.0 for our project. I have an embeded application which I want to run on boot up. I have an exe file for the same. I have tried using the systemctl command but it has not helped. I also tried editing the inittab file but that didn't help too. I also tried adding a rc.local file and edit the rc.d to add the execution of rc.local but it said that the file cannot be modified. (I was in sudo mode when I tried this).

I wish to start the application on boot up without asking a user to login. Also where should we keep our exe in filesystem so that it will be detected at startup. Can someone please guide on how can I achieve this ?

Comment: Can't write a full answer but you can [write a unit file](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=148170) for `rc.local` or just the executable you're wanting to start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following unit file as a template:

```
[Unit]
Description=A Test Service That Prints the date
After=network.target
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/myservice
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/date >> /now.txt" $MYSERVICE_ARGS
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Save it in `/etc/systemd/system/` with a `.service` file extension (for example  `/etc/systemd/system/myservice.service`)

Any environment variables that are needed by your application can be placed in `/etc/sysconfig/myservice`, including the creation of a variable to hold your command line options:

```
MYSERVICE_ARGS=--posix
```

(If you use a variable for the command line options, then add the variable to your command in `ExecStart` as follows: `ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/myservice $MYSERVICE_ARGS`)

Test it with:

```
# systemctl start myservice
```

You should now have a file `/now.txt` that has the date/time appended every time this is run.

Enable it to start at boot with:

```
# systemctl enable myservice
```

It should now start automatically after networking comes up.

Alter the `ExecStart` line to run your application.  Remember that `systemd` doesn't run `ExecStart` in a shell therefore if you need redirection, for example, then you'll need to run `bash -c` as per the example.  Also, there will not be a `$PATH` variable, therefore use full paths.  The application will be run as user `root`.

There are far more options that you can use - read the [man page](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html).  Also, browse your system's unit files in `/usr/lib/systemd/system`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. ExecStart should have the path of my executable or a shellscript file?

Comment: @Sid411 - Whichever one works for you.  If you look at the examples in `/usr/lib/` you'll see executables being called. If your application starts with just a command line invocation (maybe with some options) then that will be fine. However, it may be more complex that that, so you may need a script to start it.

Comment: I have done the same thing. Gave the path to my executable.it is still not working. Its still asking for login and if I check the status of the service it gives me the following:




Redirecting to /bin/systemctl  status TestBOSService.service
TestBOSService.service - A Test Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/TestBOSService.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Fri, 05 Dec 2014 15:52:59 +0530; 17min ago
  Process: 619 ExecStart=/home/665267/Integrated/DummyApp/DummyApp (code=dumped, signal=ABRT)
   CGroup: name=systemd:/system/TestService.service

Comment: @Sid411 - What is still asking for a login?  Note that the environment variables passed to a service are different to the ones used at the shell by a logged in user.  Maybe there is a variable that the application needs?  See [man systemd.exec](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) for all your options.